# wierd bug with vuejs 2 router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

That is part of my axios request:

```
.then(function (response) {

    self.forms.process = false;

    if( response.data.redirect ){
        console.log(123);
        router.push( { name: response.data.redirect } );
    }

})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error.response.data);
```

if I remove router.push- no errors.
But with router.go I've got an error at console.log(error.response.data) line:

- // here is printed 123 by console.log before router.push
- Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

I can't understand how to fix that bug

Comment: `router.go(n)`: "This method takes a single integer as parameter that indicates by how many steps to go forwards or go backwards in the history stack". You want `router.push()`. https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html

Comment: I've tried push too, but get the same error. Look like that's router error itself

Comment: the error doesn't always has a response so you should do on your `catch` function: `if(error.response){ console.log(error.response.data }`

Comment: What's in `response`?

Comment: That fix this error, but router still doesn't work. Just nothing happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should use self.$router.push instead of router.push